# Watir webdriver - How to click on dynamically generated last <td> in table?

Tags: watir-webdriver

In my application,I've to select the last td (which is an img) in table.Can anyone help me with this ?

HTML

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<td>
<a onclick="return confirm('Delete creative?')" href="delete.page?cid=47">
<a href="edit.page?id=47"><a href="?duplicateId=47">
<img title="Duplicate" src="/tracker/images/skin2/bolean.png">
</a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Implemenetd as below :

```
@browser.img(:src => "/tracker/images/skin2/bolean.png").click
@browser.img(:src => "/tracker/images/skin2/bolean.png").last.click
```

which is clicking on the first image.

Comment: <table><tbody><tr><td><td><a onclick="return confirm('Delete creative?')" href="delete.page?cid=47"><a href="edit.page?id=47"><a href="?duplicateId=47"><img title="Duplicate" src="/tracker/images/skin2/bolean.png"></a></td></tr></tbody></table>

Comment: if you need to incorporate additional information, EDIT your question.. it's very hard to make sense of unformatted html in a comment.  in addition the HTML above makes like zero sense, there's missing close tags galore, what appear to be nested links?? it's just a jumble, like someone tossed code in a blender and hit frappe.

Answer (score 4):

When you do:

```
@browser.img(:src => "/tracker/images/skin2/bolean.png")
```

This returns the first matching element.

If you want to get all of the matching elements, you need to pluralize the method:

```
@browser.imgs(:src => "/tracker/images/skin2/bolean.png")
```

You will then get a collection of all images that have the specified src. You can then get the last one and click it similar to how Željko did it for tds.

```
@browser.imgs(:src => "/tracker/images/skin2/bolean.png").last.click
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
@browser.tds.last.click
```